# Non-cohomological proof that a noetherian scheme $X$ is affine if its reduction $X_{red}$ is affine

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can we prove that a noetherian scheme $X$ is affine if its reduction $X_{red}$ is affine without using cohomology?

**Remark**
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161970/for-a-noetherian-scheme-x-show-that-x-red-affine-implies-x-affine) is a similar question.

Comment: The argument given in the comment to the linked question seems to answer this.  The only cohomology group invoked is an $H^1$ that could easily be defined without reference to derived functors.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I wonder how you prove that $\Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X)_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow \mathcal O_X,_{\mathfrak p}$ is an isomorphism. Regards,

Answer (score -2):

It suffices to prove the following proposition without using cohomology.

**Proposition**
Let $X$ be a scheme.
Suppose there exists a quasi coherent $\mathcal O_X$-ideal $\mathcal I$ such that $\mathcal I^2 = 0$ and $(X, \mathcal O_X/\mathcal I)$ is affine.
Let $\mathcal F$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-module.
Then $\mathcal F$ is [quasi-flasque](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734713/proof-of-a-certain-proposition-on-sheaves-without-using-cohomology).

Proof(without using cohomology):
Consider the following exact sequence.
$0 \rightarrow \mathcal I \mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F/\mathcal I\mathcal F \rightarrow 0$.
Since $\mathcal I \mathcal F$ and $\mathcal F/\mathcal I\mathcal F$ are both quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X/\mathcal I$-modules, they are quasi-flasque by my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734959/non-cohomological-proof-that-a-quasi-coherent-sheaf-over-an-affine-scheme-is-qua).
Hence $\mathcal F$ is quasi-flasque by jdc's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734713/proof-of-a-certain-proposition-on-sheaves-without-using-cohomology).